# Create a relationship model where a user can follow any of two models

Tags: django, django-models

How do I setup a model for a follow relationship, where a user can follow another user or a tag.

eg: userA is following (userB, userC, tag-Health, tag-Finance).

This was how I thought:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User)
    content_type = models.ManyToManyField(ContentType, related_name='followed_by')
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
```

But since ContentType only works for ForeignKey, how do I create a model so that a user can follow any of the two model (i.e. users and tags?